# Write Matrix $A$ to $A = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \lambda_i P_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a Matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 3i \\
  0 & -3 & 0 \\
  -3i & 0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now I want to write $A$ as $$A = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \lambda_i P_i$$

I determined all $\lambda$. But how can I now determine all the $P_i$?

Can someone give me a hint? Thank you!

Comment: what are those $\lambda_i$'s ? Do you mean eigenvalues ?

Comment: and what are $P_i$'s ? Give some details

Comment: $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues and the $P_i$'s are orthogonal projections onto the $i$-th eigenvector of $A$

Answer (score 2):

*We generalize the result for a hermitian matrix with size $n$*:

Notice that the matrix $A$ is hermitian i.e. $A^*=A$ hence it's diagonalizable so there's a matrix $U$ such that
$$A=U\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)U^*$$
so let $Q_i=\operatorname{diag}(0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)$ where the $1$ is at the $i^{\text{th}}$ position and $P_i=UQ_iU^*$ and then we have the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried to understand your comment. I don't get where I get the $U$ from? How does $U$ look like?

Comment: $U$ is just the change matrix to the basis where $A$ is diagonal and the columns of this matrix are the eigenvectors of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. (You can normalize the eigenvectors to obtain $U$ unitary).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess and say that the $\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues of $A$ and that the $P_i$'s are orthogonal projections onto the $i$-th eigenvector of $A$.

If this is correct, then $P_i = v_iv_i^T$ where $v_i$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_i$.

Also, if your matrix is complex, you shouldn't use $i$ as both $\sqrt{-1}$ and as an index variable.

Comment: So do I have only to compute the eigenvectors $v_i$ and then I can calculate $P_i$. Aren't those $P_i$'s matrices?

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix and $A = \lambda_1P_1+\lambda_2P_2+\lambda_3P_3$, then $P_1,P_2,P_3$ have to be matrices.